# Is there any method for getting the correct battery level in ios7?

Tags: iphone, ios7, batterylevel

I have displayed the battery level in a label called "batteryLevel".The code used for that is the following,

```
batteryLevel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f%%", [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel * 100];
```

But i got the battery level in 95%,90% etc.I have to show the battery level accurately,as displayed as in the current device.Is there any correct method to find out the battery level in ios7 and previous ios versions?please give me a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

best solution for you should always use the values you show using a **timer** to give the **appearance** of accuracy.

Using batteryLevel Property:

```
 [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel.
```

for more detail check :
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/BatteryStatus/Introduction/Intro.html

from above link **sample code** latest **Version 1.2** is also used the **batteryLevel** Property.

If you are use jailbroken device, you can  use

```
int percent = [(SBUIController*)[objc_getClass("SBUIController") sharedInstance] displayBatteryCapacityAsPercentage];
```

This method is present on iOS 4.3+, and is probably what Battery Doctor is using.

Comment: Will you please elaborate it ? He is using the same `[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel`.

Comment: @TheTiger he want accurate betterylevel,i give him that solution.

Comment: @Dhaval Bhadania : I checked with the apple sample code.But still i got the battery level is multiple of 5.I want the exact battery level in the device like 99%,98%,92% etc.Please give me a solution for that.

Comment: Check this link: http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/02/14/reading-the-battery-level-programmatically/ but careful about that, apple will may reject this framework.better to used the UIDevice battery monitoring method.

Comment: That blog post doesn't work for iOS 7. It worked great prior to that though.